# how do I make a WPF listview tile my results (such as a ASP.net listview)

Tags: wpf, listview

I was able to find only one C# example, but it will not run for me.

An example can be found towards the bottom of this page and is labeled "Custom View: Tile View": http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WPFListView09092008224322PM/WPFListView.aspx

I appreciate the help!

---

**Update**
Was able to achieve what I wanted by using the response to the following question: [WrapPanel doesn't wrap in WPF ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573376/wrappanel-doesnt-wrap-in-wpf-listview)

Thanks all!

Comment: Please elaborate. What's wrong with the example? Is there a specific part of the source code that doesn't illustrate the concept clearly enough? What happens when you try to run it? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: As stated, the example will not run so it does not illustrate what I need since I can not see in action exactly what parts I need to include to do what I need.  More specifically, it is referencing a class called "SDKSample" which does not exist, causing all items referencing "l" or a link to "SDKSample" to not compile correctly.  The one I specifically needs is requesting this imported reference.

Comment: Which I am aware that it's a class in the project, however it is not referencing it correctly. I can not click on properties cause I get "An error occurred trying to load the project properties window.  Close the window and try again.
Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))".  This may be an issue from up-converting to a 2010 project, but it says it was successful and in the end.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you're looking for some sample code of how to create a `ListView` that wrap/tile the `ListViewItem` s?

Comment: Yep, which I finally just found. I had to disable the horizontal scrollbar to get what I was doing to work.  Thanks though!