# Selectable controls in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls, selectable

Is there a **general** mechanism in WPF that allows for any or almost any control to be selected? For instance, you could have some *`Image`* controls on a *`WrapPanel`* defined in XAML, and you need to be able to select them either one by one, or by dragging over with the mouse to mark multiple.

In terms of code, I can imagine the following:

```
<WrapPanel> 
    <Image Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=pic1}" />
    <Image Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=pic2}" />
    <Image Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=pic3}" />
    <Image Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=pic4}" />
    <Image Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=pic5}" />
</WrapPanel>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, its called a `ListView`.

If you need the look of a `WrapPanel`, just set the `ItemsPanel` property like so:

```
<ListView>
   <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listview.aspx).

You would need to make the `Image` objects part of the ItemTemplate in your example. You can manually define the `Items` collection or use a `CompositeCollection` as the items source as well.

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked with the solution I found here: [WrapPanel doesn't wrap in WPF ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573376/wrappanel-doesnt-wrap-in-wpf-listview#2573386)

It's basically the same solution as BradleyDotNET's, but it includes ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" in the list view and by doing so, it makes the wrap function work without needing to do anything more.

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
  <ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemsPanel>
  ...
</ListView>
```