# WrapPanel in ListBox with Horizontal & Vertical Scrolling

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2573386/864101, I'm using this code:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <Image Source="http://placehold.it/50x50" Stretch="None"/>
    <Image Source="http://placehold.it/60x50" Stretch="None"/>
    <Image Source="http://placehold.it/70x50" Stretch="None"/>
    <Image Source="http://placehold.it/80x50" Stretch="None"/>
    <Image Source="http://placehold.it/90x50" Stretch="None"/>
    <Image Source="http://placehold.it/100x50" Stretch="None"/>
    <Image Source="http://placehold.it/600x200" Stretch="None"/>
</ListBox>
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

I need to have both the horizontal & vertical scrollbars, just like this (just a quick mockup using HTML):

[image]

Using `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` made the images wrap but disabled the horizontal scroll bar, which is why I can't see the rest of the `600x200` image.

I've struggled hours on this fixing this but no luck, can some please help me?

The images in the ListBox are updated with different dimensions from user input.

Comment: ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" disable scrolling in WPF APP not IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a margin:

```
<ListBox>
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel MaxWidth="600" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
<Image Margin ="5" Source="http://placehold.it/50x50" Stretch="None"/>
<Image Margin ="5" Source="http://placehold.it/60x50" Stretch="None"/>
<Image Margin ="5" Source="http://placehold.it/70x50" Stretch="None"/>
<Image Margin ="5" Source="http://placehold.it/80x50" Stretch="None"/>
<Image Margin ="5" Source="http://placehold.it/90x50" Stretch="None"/>
<Image Margin ="5" Source="http://placehold.it/100x50" Stretch="None"/>
<Image Margin ="5" Source="http://placehold.it/600x200" Stretch="None"/>
</ListBox>
```

Maybe you need a smaller margin than 5; just try. Maybe also an other value for 600.

Comment: I made a change in the XAML. Does this help? At least, scrollbar is shown now. Removed the Scollbar disabling code and added MaxWidth setting.

Comment: Thanks a huge bunch. I added in backend code to set the `MaxWidth` and now it works perfect. Thanks again!